# Deploying on beanstalk with express 4 build

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I followed the instructions here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs_express.html and it works fine if I use the aws examples.

But when I tried it by myself, the basic Express skeleton, expected to give an output of "Express \n Welcome to Express", isn't working and is giving a 502 Bad Gateway error.

I noticed that my build is with Express 4.2 whereas the aws examples use Express 3.x.

From the beanstalk logs:

```
2014/06/28 03:41:57 [error] 1930#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xxx.xx.xxx.xx, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/", host: "my-env-xxxxxxxxxn.elasticbeanstalk.com"
```

There is no database, and no code changed from the skeleton generated by express.

(And btw, it works just fine if I do a `npm start` locally on my mac)

Please help.

---

Update: The solution mentioned in the link below answer works in this case.

[502 Bad Gateway Deploying Express Generator Template on Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795357/502-bad-gateway-deploying-express-generator-template-on-elastic-beanstalk)

Though it is not clear to me exactly why AWS would execute in that order.

Comment: have you uncommented the line ` // app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

Comment: no, as the docs do not state it as necessary to test it (end of step 5). but since you suggested it, i tried. no change in the result.

Comment: The document says -- "On your local computer, comment out the static mapping in `node-express/app.js`. This step is not required, but it is a good test to see if the static mappings are configured correctly.

`//  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`"

Comment: That is mentioned in step 6. It should work at the end of step 5 itself. ... in any case, I've commented it, and it is not working.

Comment: I have just now downloaded the code form (http://elasticbeanstalk-samples-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/nodejs-example-express.zip). by default line is uncommented which is fine. then put development database info (i.e., host, user, port, password). then go to the folder run `npm install`. then `node app.js`. then on browser  `localhost:3000` is working.

Comment: Thank you for taking the trouble to do that. But that is not the problem I'm trying to solve. The downloaded code works for me too. The thing is if I start from scratch, without the db, but with simply Express 4, it doesn't work. I would like to start off with Express 4.

Comment: ooh right. sorry missed your point totally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56451/discussion-between-kamrul-and-kaya-toast).