# ExpressJS - Elastic Beanstalk 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am running a Express.js app on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk and my environment was successfully created, but when I go to my environment via the URL Amazon has created, I receive a `502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.6.2` error. While I have read other resources on StackOverflow, which suggest I rename my main file from `server.js` to `main.js` and set the `port` in a `bin/www` folder, I feel like this isn't the solution for my app. I ran `node server.js`, which is the command I believe 
Elastic Beanstalk runs and it doesn't work, (error message):

```
node server.js
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: failed to connect to [undefined:27017]
```

because I have ENV variables set up in a `.env` file, so the only way I can run my server is with foreman. This has made me think that the 502 error is the result of Elastic Beanstalk not being able to comprehend the variable and thus causing the server to fail. Can anyone confirm that I am on the right path or is this issue really because my main file is named `server.js` and not in the `bin/www` folder?

Here is my code from my `server.js` file:

```
//Load express
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router(); // get an instance of the router
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); // configure app to use bodyParser()
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var aws = require('aws-sdk');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true})); // get data from a POST method
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(cookieParser());


var port = process.env.PORT || 8080; // set the port

var DB_CONFIG = process.env.DB_CONFIGURATION;
var AWS_ACCESS_KEY = process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY;
var AWS_SECRET_KEY = process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY;
var S3_BUCKET = process.env.S3_BUCKET;

var blogDB = require('./config/blogDB.js');
mongoose.connect(blogDB.url);




require('./config/passport.js')(passport);


app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); // set ejs as the view engine

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); // set the public directory

app.use(session({ secret: 'thisisatest' }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(flash());


var routes = require('./app/routes');

app.use(routes); // use routes.js


app.listen(port);
console.log('magic is happening on port' + port);
```

and my package file:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "1.6.5",
    "ejs": "^1.0.0",
    "express": "^4.6.1",
    "express-paginate": "0.0.2",
    "mongoose": "~3.6.15",
    "mongoose-paginate": "^3.1.0",
    "serve-favicon": "*",
    "passport" : "~0.1.17",         
    "passport-local" : "~0.1.6",
    "connect-flash" : "~0.1.1",     
    "bcrypt-nodejs" : "latest",
    "morgan": "~1.0.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.0.0",
    "method-override": "~1.0.0",
    "express-session": "~1.0.0",
    "aws-sdk": "*" 
  }
}
```

Comment: You are running the nodejs app behind an nginx proxy ? Have you setup the correct reverse proxy configuration ?

Comment: @cphill: Looking at your logs, it seems that deployed application is not getting right mongoDB path `Error: failed to connect to [undefined:27017]`. Did you try setting up `NODE_ENV` to right value from EBS console?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [502 Bad Gateway Deploying Express Generator Template on Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795357/502-bad-gateway-deploying-express-generator-template-on-elastic-beanstalk)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same problem tonight. It turned out that the node app had not been started even though the portal claims that it will run `npm start` by default.

Here is what I did to fix it:

1. Create a directory named .ebextensions in the root of my project
2. Inside .ebextensions create a file named nodecommand.config
3. Inside the nodecommand.config add the following yaml:

> ```
> option_settings:
>   - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs
>     option_name: NodeCommand
>     value: "npm start"
> ```

The full instructions are available here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs_express.html

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue for me

Comment: Awesome! fixed the issue

Comment: You can also check logs with `eb logs` for possible errors that happened while deploying your NodeJS application.    
EB sort of bypasses certain errors and still says it "successfully deployed" the application.

Comment: @GiwooGustavoLee with Logs I was able to see error from Nginx as a Proxy Server trying to forward request to `IP:8081`. SO I change Node Port to 8081

Comment: A word of caution, this seems to be an outdated solution according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61782952/unknown-or-duplicate-parameter-nodecommand)

Comment: This is not necessary now in 2022, just create a file in the root of project called ( Procfile ) and add in web: npm start

Answer (score 18):

1. Add `"scripts": { "start": "node app.js" }` to your `package.json`.
   If your main js file is not `app.js`, don't forget to rename it! :)
2. In Beanstalk console: Configuration->Software add new env var: `port: 8081 (PORT: 8081)`
   [image]

**Important:** even if you add env var as `port` you still have to use `PORT` (uppercase). That is what solved my problem.
I tried to use `process.env.port`, but it did not work.
Use `process.env.PORT` instead.

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Server is listening on: ", port);
});
```

Comment: Perfect! That works fine. Thanks. The main thing was about the PORT as you told. After making PORT (all upper case in the code, process.env.PORT), it works! Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

From the EB App Dashboard, go to Configuration -> Software Configuration -> add value "npm start", or "node 'yourmainfile'" to the Node Command.

Even though AWS shows "Command to start the Node.js application. If an empty string is specified, app.js is used, then server.js, then "npm start" in that order", it looks like it doesn't run unless you specify.

Answer (score 7):

In my case the issue was my port, my express server was listening on port 80.
I just needed to change it to 8081 because i think the EB reverse proxy (nginx/apache) tries to redirect traffic to 8081 by default.

I figured it out by checking the AWS EB access logs.

Answer (score 4):

In my case it was process.env.`port` in index.js. The port was in a small case. I modified it to process.env.`PORT`

Answer (score 2):

For my case I'm sharing what worked for me for error 502 Bad Gateway Nginx.

AWS Elastic Beanstalk is using Nginx as Proxy Server for Load Balancing, even if you just started.

I went from the AWS EB Console Management to look for Error logs from Nginx. Always check log because your error might be different from others.

Now let's say your IP is `AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD`. I found out in the error, Nginx received requests from `AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD` and forward it to `AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD:8081`. And since I started Node to port `3003` in my code, so I had to change it for Production or whatever you call your AWS EB Server environment.

You can do it with ENV to maintain flexibility if you want (ENV can be added directly to EB Console). Once you put PORT to `8081`, make sure you commit because Elastic Beanstalk follow GIT rules to know which file to take, if you don't commit, it will not deploy the change.

Once you're done, use command `eb deploy` and watch it works now.

Answer (score 2):

For me the error was because I didn't set "npm start" in the software configuration section even though I did before creating the app.
Seems there was some bug and I had to set it again so kindly check whether its set or not!

Answer (score 2):

Evening all

In my experience, you typically will receive this error when you are not running Express on the correct port.

Nginx try's to route traffic from port 8081 to the server, which could be load balanced.

As such, you should explicitly ensure you use port 8081 as your Express listening port (e.g process.env.PORT=8081)

Thanks

Keaton

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the scripts section in your package.json file looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
     //whatever other scripts

     "start": "node app.js",

     //whatever other scripts
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing this but it was because of absense of one of the `npm module`. You can see the missing `npm model` name in the log section of elastic beanstalk dashboard. It was working fine in my local machine just because that particular npm module was globally installed in my system.

Answer (score 1):

I forget to run npm install after cloning, sudo npm install worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `NodeStart` is now considered "legacy":

> You can add a Procfile to your source bundle to specify the command that starts your application, as the following example shows. This feature replaces the legacy NodeCommand option in the aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs namespace.

The same document (source below) states:

> When you don't provide a Procfile, Elastic Beanstalk runs `npm start` if you provide a `package.json` file. If you don't provide that either, Elastic Beanstalk looks for the file `app.js` or `server.js`, in this order, and runs it.

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs.container.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a .ebextensions anymore to fix this error just follow the next steps.

First of all, you should go look at the logs that your environment throws. (Select the first records, it normally appears like this in the AWS Console in your environment.) Then look at what port it is throwing at you, if it is 8080 or 8081, which is the most common, once this is clear, then it directs you to configuration in your current environment, and add an environment variable called port and add the port that appears in your logs (registry that you have looked at recently) of the environment in which you are working, finally verify that in your main file (index.js or app.js whatever!!) the one that starts your server , you have this `const PORT = process.env.port || 5900;`... ***And finally, also have a file in your project in the root, if not just create then..*** which is called **Procfile** and within said file you add the following line: **`web: npm start`**, what this line does is start your application in bs(beanstealk), I will leave some images for more details.

***First capture.***
[image: First step to fix the error 502]

***Second capture.***
[image: First step to fix the error 502]

And now, just go to your project folder and do,

- `git add .` then do > `git commit -m "Updated or whatever"`

*finally run the eb cmd* ... `eb deploy`

Answer (score 0):

In my case the node app was working fine until I added an AWS' CodePipeline to automatically upload code to Elastic Beanstalk from GitHub. To resolve this I untracked the node_modules directory. [If Elastic Beanstalk detects the node_modules directory, Elastic Beanstalk doesn't run npm install, even if a package.json file exists.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-platform-dependencies.html)