# Cannot find module 'cookie-Parser' -- aws elastic beastalk

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services

I completed my node, postgres, angular project and is working on deployment. I recently learned about aws elastic beanstalk and for 2 days now, i have been trying unsuccessfully to deploy my project on it :( . Its been two days and really frustrating.

My project structure was like below initially

[image]

I now changed it to below after reading here that express expect .bin/www to be the starting file. I also rename my server.js to main.js  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795357/502-bad-gateway-deploying-express-generator-template-on-elastic-beanstalk)

[image]

Despite my attempt, my project is still showing "Bad gateway 502" after deployment. I read many post about this and spent many hours.

My package.json was exactly below initially.

```
{
  "name": "nairamarket",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "bin/www.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node bin/www.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "4.2.1",
    "npm": "2.14.7"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "email-templates": "^2.3.0",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "express-session": "^1.13.0",
    "jade": "^1.11.0",
    "moment": "^2.12.0",
    "node-uuid": "^1.4.7",
    "nodemailer": "^2.2.1",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "pg": "^4.4.4",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.2",
    "sequelize": "^3.19.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.7.7",
    "nodemon": "^1.8.1",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0",
    "multer": "^1.1.0",
    "node-sass-middleware": "^0.9.7",
  }
}
```

After analyzing my aws log , i saw cannot find module morgan. I then realised may be the npm install does not install devs. I then move

```
"morgan": "^1.7.0",
"multer": "^1.1.0",
"node-sass-middleware": "^0.9.7",
```

TO my dependecies . The error still persist for body-parser and cookie-parser. I then disabled the two to test and see. My problem still persist. When i analysed the logs again, below is what i saw.

```
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     NODE_ENV=production npm install && node bin/www.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs nairamarket
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     npm owner ls nairamarket
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

And under ngix error . I noticed the error below

```
[error] 7987#0: *2 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream,
```

Below is part of my main.js and my bin/www.js just import the main.js

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8081);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('its listening', server.address().port);
    debug('Express server listen on port', + server.address().port)
});

debug('PORT' + process.env.PORT);
debug('PARAM1' + process.env.PARAM1);
debug('PARAM2' + process.env.PARAM2);
debug('PARAM3' + process.env.PARAM3);
debug('PARAM4' + process.env.PARAM4);
debug('PARAM5' + process.env.PARAM5);
```

Please i would appreciate any tutorial or guidance with regard to this issue. Have worked on it for over two days and yet no solution.I also noticed like the node_modules/npm install is not restarting, like it has been cached . Please how do i addressed this issue and deploy my app ? Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**

I changed my start to

```
"start": "NODE_ENV=production npm install && node bin/www",
```

as suggested my molda below. However, it does not reflect the changes . I deployed over 3 times , yet it display node bin/www.js regardless.

I learnt that my zip or upload name need to match the name of my environment. I did do that. Now i am having the error below

```
fs.js:808
  return binding.readdir(pathModule._makeLong(path));
```

And for ngix

```
 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream,
```

Althougth i don't quite understood what the error implies, i am suspecting my

```
_driname
```

I have a file call root.js and it contained is below.

var path = require('path');

```
var dirname = path.resolve(path.resolve(__dirname));

var rootPath = path.normalize(dirname);


module.exports = rootPath;
```

I then reference my root.js in my config file which is two folders inward .

config.js

```
var rootPath = require('../../root');
```

I am not sure if the error is related with that but i am quite suspecting.

Comment: This line `npm ERR!     NODE_ENV=production npm install && node bin/www.js` has extra `.js` at the end, check your package.json for the start script and remove .js if it's there

Comment: @Molda thanks for the response.  Please i updated my question, do have a look.

Comment: I'm not sure what you updated. Can you show the script section of package.json?

Answer (score 0):

This happened because i spell cookie-parser wrong . Its.

```
var cookieParser= require('cookie-parser');
```

not

```
require('cookie-Parser)
```

Note the capital P in parser. Sadly took me a while to realised that. The remain errors are due to my aws seucrity groups between elastic beanstalk and rds.