# Nodejs/express api fails at 502 bad gateway on elastic beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've attempted to launch a nodejs/express api on Elastic Beanstalk.

When I run the api locally, it works perfectly.

When I go to the URL given by elastic beanstalk, I reach a 502 bad gateway.

This is the error log that I receive:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/var/app/current/main.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! backend@1.0.0 start: `node main.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the backend@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

> backend@1.0.0 start /var/app/current
> node main.js

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
```

This is my main.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const passport = require("passport")
// const teamRoutes = express.Router()
const PORT = 4000

//app imports
const { teamRouter } = require('./routers')
const { playerRouter } = require('./routers')
const { reportRouter } = require('./routers')
const { likeRouter } = require('./routers')
const { leagueRouter } = require('./routers')
const { filterRouter } = require('./routers')
const { commentRouter } = require('./routers')
const { adminUserRouter } = require('./routers')
const { tokenRouter } = require('./routers')

let Team = require('./models/Team')

app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json())

mongoose.connect('mymongodb', { useNewUrlParser: true})
const connection = mongoose.connection

connection.once('open', function(){
    console.log('MongoDB database connection established!')
})

// Passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
// Passport config
require("./config/passport")(passport);


app.use('/teams', teamRouter)
app.use('/players', playerRouter)
app.use('/reports', reportRouter)
app.use('/likes', likeRouter)
app.use('/leagues', leagueRouter)
app.use('/filters', filterRouter)
app.use('/comments', commentRouter)
app.use('/api/users', adminUserRouter)
app.use('/tokens', tokenRouter)


app.listen(PORT, function() {
    console.log('Server is running on Port: ' + PORT)
})
```

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node main.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "concurrently": "^4.1.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "expo-server-sdk": "^3.3.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "grunt": "^1.0.4",
    "is-empty": "^1.2.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.6.4",
    "mongoose-deep-populate": "^3.1.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.3.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "validator": "^11.1.0"
  }
}
```

My main.js used to be called server.js, but I changed it based on the recommendation of this post:
[502 Bad Gateway Deploying Express Generator Template on Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795357/502-bad-gateway-deploying-express-generator-template-on-elastic-beanstalk)

Edit:
This is my file path:

[image]

Edit:
This is my .elasticbeanstalk config.yml file:

```
branch-defaults:
  default:
    environment: news-arg-backend
    group_suffix: null
global:
  application_name: news-arg-backend
  branch: null
  default_ec2_keyname: null
  default_platform: Node.js
  default_region: us-west-2
  include_git_submodules: true
  instance_profile: null
  platform_name: null
  platform_version: null
  profile: eb-cli
  repository: null
  sc: null
  workspace_type: Application
```

In my .ebextensions, I have a nodecommand.config and a settings.config.

This is my nodecommad.config:

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs
    option_name: NodeCommand
    value: "npm start"
```

This is my settings.config:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs:staticfiles:
    option_name: /static/
    value: /public/
```

Comment: is the main.js on the root? and where is the app.js? might be https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/1846

Comment: @Adiii i edited the post to show my file path. there is no app.js; this is only an api. could that be tripping it up?

Comment: @schoenbl what configuration do you have in .ebextansion and .elasticbeanstalk

Comment: @SandeepPatel I just updated it to include my .ebextansion and my .elasticbeanstalk